# Master password for Spring security user authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, passwords

in my security xml file

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select email,password, 'true' as enabled from users where lower(email)=lower(?) and activestatus='1' "
                authorities-by-username-query="select u.entityid,e.entityname from entity e, users u where e.entityid = u.entityid and lower(u.email)=lower(?) and u.activeStatus='1';" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

I would like to create a master password; lets say "password123" to allow me to login to any account.

What kind of edits should be done to make this possible?

Comment: What makes you believe such a thing is possible, and how would that be compatible with user security and privacy?  You are asking to create a back door and single point of failure.

Comment: correct. i want a master password for my dev machine for easy access.

Comment: Despite this causing a huge security hole, you would have to write your own Authentication Provider which will check for your backdoor password first, before passing the authentication request on to the underlying database-based authentication provider. Please don't do it, or at least let us know what project this is so we can make sure we never use it.

Comment: any clues on how to achieve this? I understand how bad it might be but for my needs this is important for my dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a great idea.

Instead, I would recommend looking at the Switch User feature:

http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/user-impersonation-with-spring-security/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.html

Comment: the answer tends to be a link only answer. could you extend it further for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this in any programmatic way.  I see no reason to have something like this in your codebase.

If you really want to have similar functionality for dev, you can simply update all the user passwords to the same value in your DB that you're using for dev.

Your DB schema will vary, but I mean something like:

> UPDATE `schemaname`.`ACCOUNT` SET `password`='someEncrytedString'
>   WHERE `USER_ID`>='1';

Note that Spring Security will use an encrypted string, so you'd be pasting in an encrypted value and not clear text.

I gather you only want this for dev and I'm thinking a more elaborate solution using `SwitchUserFilter` may be overengineering.

We've done it for years this way and it's been fine. The advantage to just changing the passwords is that other users will not be affected at all and the only way to harm production is to accidentally run the query against an unsecured production DB.  In which case, well, you'd probably deserve the outcome.